# Do I need to queue each message sent on Laravel or Pusher?

Tags: laravel, react-native, pusher

I'm trying to build a React Native chatting app using Pusher and Laravel as the backend. I want to know more about this environment, do I need to queue each message sent and receive by the user on my backend or just let Pusher do the job? Or it doesn't need a queue at all?? Which is the most suitable in this case?

Comment: https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-react-native

Comment: thanks for the reference @Martin Bean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to queue the messages, you can just send them and let Pusher broadcast them to the necessary subscribed clients. However, you should consider queuing or other solutions if you need sequential delivery or to retrieve messages that were not received correctly. 
Check out their [help page](https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019262174-How-do-I-implement-message-event-history-for-Channels-) for a discussion on how to do this.

Comment: thanks for the information. i'll take a look and test it later.